How to switch on INFO messages on Spring boot console - Eclipse project
I am finding it difficult to debug my spring boot mvc application which used to show the INFO/Warning/Error messages some time ago. I did play with the project settings/configs some time ago and it broke the logging setup. All I get now is the following:
LF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

I appreciate Spring boot offers slf4j by default with logback implementation which is responsible to log messages on the console. However, something is broken now which is why I can't see errors (from View layer) on console.
I tried adding root level logging to info on application.properties and searching for any logger implementation within my classes.
Any clues/ideas on what else could be checked to get back the console logging?
Thanks.

After the jar file was created using maven build, the app produced the log messages as expected. i.e executing the application outside of the eclipse ide resolves the logging issue that I reported earlier. so the root cause of the problem is within eclipse setting which is suppressing all the logging messages.
